# How to count how many times a value is preceded and followed by a sequence of another value?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's consider the following Series:

```py
0    A
1    B
2    A
3    C
4    C
5    D
6    A
7    B
8    A
```

Let's also suppose that we'd like to see how many times `B` is preceded and followed by a single 'A'. In the example above, this happens 2 times!

One way to calculate this would be:

```py
(s.shift(-1).eq('A') & s.shift(1).eq('A') & s.eq('B')).sum()
```

However, we might have wanted to see how many times a `B` is preceded by `n` consecutive `A` and followed by `n` consecutive `A` respectively (and not just a single `A`).

For example,

```py
0    A
1    A
2    A
3    B
4    A
5    A
6    A
```

For `n = 3`, this happens exactly once in the above example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Naive version

Let starts with the naive version (what not to do! But it can be used as a basis to validate the less naive one)

```py
def naive(df, A, B, n):
    tot=0
    for i in range(n, len(df)-n):
        if df.iloc[i, 0]==A:
            ok=True
            for j in range(i-n, i):
                if df.iloc[j, 0]!=B:
                     ok=False
            for j in range(i+1, i+n+1):
                if df.iloc[j, 0]!=B:
                     ok=False
            if ok: tot+=1
    return tot
```

So, just using dataframe as a list, iterate ourselves on it, and check what we want to check. Here counting the number of occurrence of A that are preceded and succeeded by n occurrences of B.
We know it is not a good idea. Because generally speaking, iterating over pandas rows never is. But it works

Let test it

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

l=np.random.choice(['A','B', 'C'], 1000).tolist()

df=pd.DataFrame({'c':l})

naive(df, 'A', 'B', 3) # number of times we find 3 'B' then one 'A', then 3 'B'.
```

### `sliding_window_view`

Now, the less naive one. Not ideal, since I rely on numpy. But, well, there is an underlying numpy array, so it is not like I was really converting datas.

```py
def strideBased(df, A, B, n):
    view=np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(df.c.values, 2*n+1)
    comp=[B]*n+[A]+[B]*n
    return np.all(view==comp, axis=1).sum()
```

### Explanation:

`np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(array, k)` is a 2d array, showing sliding windows on the 1d array array.

For example `np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(np.array([1,2,3,3,10,3,20]), 3)`
is

```
array([[1,  2,  3],
       [2,  3,  3],
       [3,  3,  10],
       [3,  10, 3],
       [10, 3,  20]])
```

So, if you are wondering how many times a 10 is surrounded by 1 `3` on each side, well, it is easy, it is the number of times you see a line `[3,10,3]` in this view.

Note that this is a "view". So no 2D array is really created here. It just the same data presented otherwise.

Here `[3,10,3]` is what I've called `comp`. It is `[3]*1+[10]+[3]*1` (assuming still the same example, that is A=10, B=3, n=1).

Now, this `view==comp` is an array of booleans comparing each values. In my example

```
array([[False,  False,  True],
       [False,  False,  True],
       [True,   False,  False],
       [True,   True,   True],
       [False,  False,  False]])
```

(Note, if you have a really big array as input, this is where it can break. Because, "view" was just a view, with no new memory, or almost so, allocated. But this array of booleans is really built. So, if data is big, you way want to do this comparison by slices of say, 10000 lines of view)

So, just a number/number comparison

Calling `np.all` on that aggreate each line (because axis=1) in a single bool which is True iff all are True. So in my example `[False, False, False, True, False]`

And then `.sum()` of that (counting True as 1, False as 0) is 1.

A little bit harder to understand than the naive version. But way faster!

### Sliced version

As I said, if your array is really big, and n is not too small, say, if you have 10 millions lines (not too much to fit in memory, nowadays), and you want to check if you find 'A' surrounded by 100 'B' on each sides, then the view `view=sliding_window_view(df.values, 201)` will be a 9999800×201 array. Not a problem. It is just a view. It is the same data as in df.
But `view==comp` would be a 9999800×201 array of booleans. And even if they are just booleans, that may not fit in memory.

So, for that, the idea is to reintroduce a python for loop. But one that would not do much iterations, so that 99,9% of the CPU is still spend inside numpy functions (in other words, the time spend by iterating in python is negligible)

```
N=10000 # Size of a slide. The bigger, the more memory you use
        # but the more negligible python iterations are
        # 10000 is a good compromise. Timings are essentially
        # the same as previous version. Yet, 10000 lines even
        # with n=1000, so 2001 columns, of booleans is not a big deal
def slicedStrideBased(df, A, B, n):
    view=np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(df.c.values, 2*n+1)
    comp=[B]*n+[A]+[B]*n
    tot=0
    for i in range(0, len(view), N):
        tot+=np.all(view==comp, axis=1).sum()
    return tot
```

### Timings

Timings on 1000 rows generated dataframe:

| Method | Timing |
| --- | --- |
| Naive | 165.77 |
| Stride based | 0.37 |
| Same sliced | 0.37 |

Comment: Shouldn't it be `comp = [B]*n + [A] + [B]*n` to account for both preceding and succeeding sequences? Moreover, I guess the sliding window should be 2*n + 1 in that case. What's your opinion?

Comment: I did not get that part, indeed. If we want to check both precding and succeeding sequences, yes it should be `comp=[B]*n + [A] + [B]*n`. And then second argument of sliding_window_view should be `2*n+1`, not` n+1`. I edit my answer accordingly

Comment: Edited. I also added a "sliced" version, that compare `view` with `comp` only by bunch of 10000 lines, to avoid memory problem with big arrays.

Comment: Thanks for going in depth in your answer. Pretty good explanation too!